# Try and Except Implementation Questions

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-requests, try-catch

I was given a file that contained a list of countries and the continents they're located on. The instructions for the assignment were to use a try and except function to produce a dictionary with keys of continents and the corresponding countries to each continent would be the values. I managed to use for loops to solve this problem, but I don't how I would go about using try and except functions. I've tried doing it, but I have received lots of error messages when testing the program out. I was wondering how a try and except function should be implemented to solve the problem in the assignment.

The list given to us outputs the country info as such:

```
print(countries[0])
```

Here, Andorra has been selected and the output is:

```
{'timezones': ['Europe/Andorra'], 'code': 'AD', 'continent': 'Europe', 
'name': 'Andorra', 'capital': 'Andorra la Vella'}
```

My code:

```
from countries import countries
from pprint import pprint


continent_countries = {}
i=0

for country in countries:
#try:  
    continent_inputter = {country['continent']:[]}
    continent_countries.update(continent_inputter)
#except KeyError:
# print("TESTING. NONE. TRY AGAIN. ")

for country in countries:
    if 'Europe' == country['continent']:
        continent_countries['Europe'].append(country['name'])

    elif 'Oceania' == country['continent']:
        continent_countries['Oceania'].append(country['name'])

    elif 'Africa' == country['continent']:
        continent_countries['Africa'].append(country['name'])

    elif 'North America' == country['continent']:
        continent_countries['North America'].append(country['name'])

    elif 'South America' == country['continent']:
         continent_countries['South America'].append(country['name'])

    elif 'Asia' == country['continent']:
          continent_countries['Asia'].append(country['name'])
    i+=1

print(continent_countries)
```

Comment: Try/Except **clauses** are used to account for exceptional conditions that would normally halt/break your program. You certainly can't swap a loop for a try block and expect the same functionality. Consider reading this and editing with what you think would be correct : https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html

Comment: *I have received lots of error messages* is an absolutely meaningless problem description unless you include those error messages. If you're having difficulties understanding your assignment, ask your instructor for help. They gave it to you and know exactly what's been covered in your course so far, and they're being paid to answer your questions.

Comment: Why did you post this question again?

Answer (score 1):

```
for country in countries:
    continent = country['continent']
    if continent_countries.get(continent) is None:
        continent_countries[continent] = [country['name']]
    else:
        continent_countries[continent].append(country['name'])
```